# Get cursor position in contenteditable by coordinates

Tags: javascript, position, cursor, mouse, contenteditable

I develop application with `contenteditable` elements and drag & drop feature for some span elements. The goal is to drag span element and drop it in `contenteditable` element.

What I have now - while dragging, on `document.onmouseup` event I get target element (from `event.toElement` property) so I can easily remove dropped element from parent and append where it was dropped.

What I need - cursor/carret position (equivalent of input `selectionStart` property) for `contenteditable` element by given mouse event coordinates. This is tricky.

I know there is `window.getSelection()` and it works perfectly good, but only if cursor is really there. While I am doing drag&drop, cursor is not in `contenteditable` element.

I've tried running `event.toElement.focus()` when dropping, but of course cursor goes to position 0. Also I've played with `document.elementFromPoint(x, y)` but it returns whole element, I can trigger `click()` on it, but same results -

Is there any way that to get cursor position by coordinates?

Comment: hi Mateus, did you manage to solve this problem?

Comment: Hey, we sorted it out using loop that is removing last char from contenteditable and checking if new width of element is lower than mouse event relative X coordinate. When it happens, you can get contenteditable text length as cursor position and restore original content. It works only for single text line elements. Not perfect, but was working good enough for couple of weeks, then we dropped that feature in general.